# Can smartphones power a MCU circuit through an NFC tag?

Tags: microcontroller, power, communication, low-power, nfc

NFC tags are passive *devices* and get their power from the NFC reader/writer. For my question, I'm specifically asking for recent smartphones as NFC readers/writers.

Does the phone transmit enough power to the NFC tag for driving a small microcontroller (say the [Attiny 13A](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/doc8126.pdf) which draws around 0.19mA in active mode) and some peripheral devices?

Regardless of the answer, **how** much power could you usually expect to be *transmitted* when the phone and the tag have a maximum distance of 2cm?

---

*Example Case:* **A passive info display.** As soon as you touch the tag with your phone, the MCU is being powered and booted while the phone reads location information from the tag (i.e. `New York City`). The phone than makes a web request to get NYC's current air pollution level from a public API. This data is finally being written to the tag (without overwriting the location) and the MCU draws the data onto an E-Ink display (let's assume the drawing process takes 15mA). Finally, the phone can be removed and the power is lost - whereas the data stays visible, thanks to the E-Ink technology.

Comment: Yes, this is very unspecific. Hence, the Example Case for you to get a better understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every NFC tag **is** an MCU. (So, that answers your title: yes.)

The Attiny is probably not the tool of choice here. There's NFC devices meant for pretty much what you describe: changing what is displayed.

When you look at a few larger stores, you'll find they have e-paper displays that show the price of the wares on the shelves, and these things are wirelessly updated. I don't remember whether they have a secondary power source (e.g. a coin cell) to help change the display – either way, that would be good enough for the application you describe.

So, look at e-Paper in-store price tags that are wirelessly reprogrammed. Pretty much what you want.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed I have thought about those e-paper price tags. I was just assuming they all had some power source included. As I'm especially interested in making a very thin device (speaking of a few millimeters of thickness incl. breadboard and display), I was just wondering if it could work **without** any sort of battery. I have no experience in this and I've not found any data on the internet about how much you could draw from just a regular NFC-enabled smartphone. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: The respective NFC standards fully specify that, so you'll want to do a bit more wikipedia research.